# rospack command not found

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,
while trying to build my package in ROS, after typing sudo make in the terminal, i have:

make: rospack: Command not found
Makefile:1: /cmake.mk: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target `/cmake.mk'.  Stop.

I think that should be a permission problem, so that root can not see rospack. Can anyone help me with that please? How shall i solve this?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/75649/rospack-command-not-found./) by [Yami](https://answers.ros.org/users/6274/yami/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-08-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Yami](https://answers.ros.org/users/6274/yami/) on 2013-08-29**:
ls -l
total 212
drwxr-xr-x 13 root   root     4096 Aug 13 13:13 build
drwxr-xr-x  2 nazemi nazemi   4096 Aug 29 15:25 Desktop
drwxr-xr-x  2 nazemi nazemi   4096 Aug 13 10:21 Documents
drwxr-xr-x  3 nazemi nazemi   4096 Aug 27 12:53 Downloads
-rw-r--r--  1 nazemi nazemi   8445 Aug 13 10:16 examples.desktop
drwxrwxr-x  8 nazemi nazemi   4096 Aug 16 13:37 fuerte
-rw-rw-r--  1 nazemi nazemi 147512 Aug 13 17:32 iniKarte.pgm
-rw-rw-r--  1 nazemi nazemi    136 Aug 13 17:32 iniKarte.yaml
drwxr-xr-x  2 nazemi nazemi   4096 Aug 13 10:21 Music
drwxr-xr-x  2 nazemi nazemi   4096 Aug 13 10:21 Pictures
drwxr-xr-x  2 nazemi nazemi   4096 Aug 13 10:21 Public
drwxr-xr-x 16 nazemi nazemi   4096 Aug 29 16:30 ros_stacks
drwxr-xr-x  2 nazemi nazemi   4096 Aug 13 10:21 Templates
drwxr-xr-x  2 nazemi nazemi   4096 Aug 13 10:21 Videos
drwxr-xr-x 20 nazemi nazemi   4096 Aug 13 10:51 youbot_driver

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2013-08-29**:
You shouldn't be doing make as root.

**Comment by [Yami](https://answers.ros.org/users/6274/yami/) on 2013-08-30**:
in this case i just have a pile of errors and warnings,as below:

$ make
[rospack] Warning: error while crawling /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/openni_camera/info: boost::filesystem::directory_iterator::construct: Permission denied: "/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/openni_camera/info"
[rospack] Warning: error while looking for /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/openni_camera/info/rospack_nosubdirs: boost::filesystem::status: Permission denied: "/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/openni_camera/info/rospack_nosubdirs"
[rospack] Warning: error while looking for /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/openni_camera/info/manifest.xml: boost::filesystem::status: Permission denied: "/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/openni_camera/info/manifest.xml"
[rospack] Warning: error while crawling /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/openni_camera/info: boost::filesystem::directory_iterator::construct: Permission denied: "/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/openni_camera/info"
[rospack] Warning: error while crawling /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/openni_camera/launch: boost::filesystem::directory_iterato

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2013-08-30**:
If you have run make as root somewhere in your /opt/ros/fuerte folder, you've probably messed up the installation. Your best bet of recovery is to uninstall all ros-fuerte-* packages (using Synaptic, aptitude, whatever) and reinstall them. Then never run make as root again.

**Comment by [Yami](https://answers.ros.org/users/6274/yami/) on 2013-08-30**:
no i did not do that in  /opt/ros/fuerte folder, but in the folder that my new package is placed:
~/ros_stacks/simple_navigation_goals$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Why do you need to execute "make" as root?

When you do "sudo make" all the environment variables needed for ROS to work (set by /opt/ros/groovy/setup.bash) are not set any more, that is why rospack can not be found.

You should, either:

-Not run make as root (recommended)

or

-Set /opt/ros/groovy/setup.bash for the root user

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2013-08-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Yami](https://answers.ros.org/users/6274/yami/) on 2013-08-30**:
Thanks for your answers first of all, but running not as root does not help. I also found this:
http://answers.ros.org/question/30554/rospack-command-not-found-in-makefile-when-trying-to-build/

but have no idea how he has the problem solved !  :(

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2013-08-30**:
I'd seriously advise against option (2). Only do that when you know *exactly* what you're doing *and* have a good reason to *and* made sure you're not accidentally changing files in /opt/ros/*. A good rule of thumb is that if you know enough to safely do this, you probably know a better way, too. :)

**Comment by [Yami](https://answers.ros.org/users/6274/yami/) on 2013-08-30**:
As said $ make  produces:
[rospack] Warning: error while crawling /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/openni_camera/info: boost::filesystem::directory_iterator::construct: Permission denied: "/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/openni_camera/info" [rospack] Warning: error while looking for /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/openni_camera/info/rospack_nosubdirs: boost::filesystem::status: Permission denied: "/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/openni_camera/info/rospack_nosubdirs" [rospack] Warning: error while looking for /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/openni_camera/info/manifest.xml: boost::filesystem::status: Permission denied: "/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/openni_camera/info/manifest.xml" [rospack] Warning: error while crawling /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/openni_camera/info: boost::filesystem::directory_iterator::construct: Permission denied: "/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/openni_camera/info" [rospack] Warning: error while crawling /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/openni_camera/launch: boost::filesystem::directory_iterato

**Comment by [Yami](https://answers.ros.org/users/6274/yami/) on 2013-08-30**:
I also should admit i'm totally new to Ubuntu and ROS

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2013-08-30**:
@Yami: If you reinstall ros, everything in /opt/ros should be readable by your normal user. Whenever you want to modify something, copy it to your home dir instead and put that dir on your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH. That way you can safely edit stuff.

**Comment by [Yami](https://answers.ros.org/users/6274/yami/) on 2013-08-30**:
Thanks Martin.
Now I have:
~/ros_stacks/simple_navigation_goals$ ls -l
drwxrwxr-x 2 nazemi nazemi 4096 Aug 30 08:50 bin
drwxrwxr-x 3 nazemi nazemi 4096 Aug 30 12:26 build
-rw-rw-r-- 1 nazemi nazemi 1517 Aug 30 10:23 CMakeLists.txt
drwxrwxr-x 3 nazemi nazemi 4096 Aug 29 16:30 include
-rw-rw-r-- 1 nazemi nazemi  128 Aug 29 16:30 mainpage.dox
-rw-rw-r-- 1 nazemi nazemi   41 Aug 29 16:30 Makefile
-rw-rw-r-- 1 nazemi nazemi  404 Aug 30 09:37 manifest.xml
drwxrwxr-x 2 nazemi nazemi 4096 Aug 30 09:00 src

**Comment by [Yami](https://answers.ros.org/users/6274/yami/) on 2013-08-30**:
drwxrwxr-x 2 nazemi nazemi 4096 Aug 30 08:50 bin

**Comment by [Yami](https://answers.ros.org/users/6274/yami/) on 2013-08-30**:
drwxrwxr-x 3 nazemi nazemi 4096 Aug 30 12:26 build

**Comment by [Yami](https://answers.ros.org/users/6274/yami/) on 2013-08-30**:
So u think I shouls reinstall ros? to be able to change build?